# Do users see other cards on the boards?

Tags: trello

I would like to know how much the users I invite to the boards see?
Do they see other cards, which they are not assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, inviting a user to a board allows them to view all cards.

Subscribing/Assigning users to a card simply allows them to receive notifications when the card is edited, commented on etc.